# Keyboard shortcut to jump between terminal commands

Tags: keyboard, shortcuts

I have the latest version of Ubuntu installed on my Mac laptop (so I’m dealing with a Mac keyboard layout).

When using the terminal, I want to be able to jump between commands that I’ve previously typed using a keyboard shortcut. Any idea what I need to press?

On a Mac OS X operating system I would press and hold the CMD key and use the up and down directional arrows. I want the Ubuntu equivalent.

I could scroll but a shortcut is useful for skipping the output of commands that generate a lot of STDOUT noise.

Comment: How about the up and down arrows, or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: The up and down arrows show the past commands so I can hit return and re-execute the command.

But I don't want to re-execute it, instead I want to jump past all the STDOUT and scroll to where I originally executed the command. If I still had the Mac OS installed I'd created a GIF.

Comment: That is not how it works. The prompt is where any command is entered. You can recall previous commands using arrow keys, you can also use Ctrl+R to search for a previous command, and take it over on the current for editing or execution.

Comment: So what can be done on Mac OS X can’t be done in Ubuntu? I’m just double checkin I understand what you’re saying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The feature you are looking for unfortunately is not available in the Ubuntu terminal. The closest you could get to quickly move to a previous command in the terminal output, is to use the Find function. You can search for your prompt. Once the search string is entered, it will more or less work as you want. The entered search string remains active throughout your session until you change it, and you can use hotkeys to quickly jump to the previous or next instance.

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> will summon the "Find" dialog (you can also click on the magnifying glass). If you enter a part of your terminal prompt there, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to remember the string and do a first searh. Then, you can press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to close the dialog and continue searching using

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd>

too search forwards, and

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>

to search backward for the string. At that moment, it will work somehow like you would have wanted.

Comment: Thanks. It's a shame the feature does not exist. It's something I'd like to see on Ubuntu as I used it quite a bit during my time on OS X.

Comment: Once I fully understood your question, I saw this would indeed be a valid feature request. As far as I see, more advanced terminal emulators such as Tilix and Terminator also do not offer more advanced features in this respect.